# polymer on-tap can't work in everywhere on-click can

Tags: mobile, polymer

```
 <div class="list-group bg-light no-border list-group-opt no-radius m-b-none">
            <a class="list-group-item"  on-tap="enterIndividual">
                <div class="primary-info"
                    <div class="pull-left w-1x">
                        <img src={{avatar}} class="w-full r-3x"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pull-left m-l intro">
                        <span class="text-lg font-bold text-black m-b-sm">{{name}}</span>
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>

                        <div class="text-muted long-intro">
                            <span>{{detail}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
```

It works well in computer,but when I tested it in my mobile,it had no react for touching.But if I use on-click instead of on-tap,it performs pretty well.So I am puzzled with this problem.Are there any requirement to use on-tap.Oh,it still has a strange point.If I touch it above a half of the div,it can work.What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, there are some errors in the code:

- close the `div.primary-info` tag
- `a-tags` are not allowed (HTML5) to contain block elements (div) - usually not a problem, but can cause some and will definitely not validate.

I guess your problem is, that the `a-tag` enclosing everything does not have the proper height and width. Try to give it a background and u'll see how large the a-tag is actually rendered as the tappable area.

U can simply skip the a-tag and move your event `on-tag` to the `div.primary-info`